# how does dbcontext map the queries into the correct navigational properties, and its efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework-core

I'm still new to EF Core and SQL in general. I have spent a few hours trying to improve efficiency, but sometimes the relational navigational properties are not matched, but other times they are.

I have a query like this:

```
return dbContext.Exhibits.Where(predicate)
            .Include(ex => ex.ParentCase)
            .Include(ex => ex.ParentExhibit)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.SubTaskings)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.User)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.Role);
```

As others here have pointed out, you generally want to avoid more than 2 includes in 1 query. So I tried something like this:

```
var exhibits = dbContext.Exhibits.Where(predicate);
exhibits.Select(ex => ex.ParentCase).Load();
exhibits.Select(ex => ex.ParentExhibit).Load();
blah blah blah
then return exhibits;
```

Now, this worked, but it's just as slow as the multiple includes.

Upon some research, people said that I can simply do something like this and the context can auto-match the navigational properties.

So I tried this:

```
var exhibits = dbContext.Exhibits.Where(predicate);
var parentCases = exhibits.Select(ex => ex.ParentCase);
var parentExhibit = exhibits.Select(ex => ex.ParentExhibit);
blah blah blah
then return exhibits;   // the same IQueryable object as above.
```

This worked for a few tries and reduced the query time from 400+ms to 70ms+ but it has just stopped working today with no code changes because all the navigational properties like tasking, parentsExhibit and parentCase are all null.

But inside the function when debugging, each var has a value. Just not auto matched to the exhibits.

I must be doing something wrong here, can anyone explain how dbcontext can match navigational properties automatically and how I can improve this multi include query? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EF generates cartesian explosion in your case: Exhibits * Taskings * Subtaskings. If this number of records is big - you have slow query.
In your case, you, probably, can improve query only by `AsSplitQuery()` call.

```cs
return dbContext.Exhibits.Where(predicate)
            .Include(ex => ex.ParentCase)
            .Include(ex => ex.ParentExhibit)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.SubTaskings)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.User)
            .Include(ex => ex.Taskings).ThenInclude(ta => ta.Role)
            .AsSplitQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you. this is what i have been using thanks to you. do you happen to know how dbcontext can automatically load queries into the corresponding navigational properties when queried?

Comment: @HeChuan, I didn't  get a question.